# Differences between Chart.js and dygraphs JavaScript libraries regarding performance and longevity

Tags: chart.js, dygraphs

I have a project where i have to present data using a JavaScript library. First, i tried **Chart.js** with unsatisfying results. My data comes from a server by an XMLHttpRequest. I have noticed that data from approximately 100 data points my chart becomes considerably slower. After about 300 data points it becomes almost unusbale. Especially the zoom plugin. Zooming is nearly impossible. The client machine is very fast, so this should not be the issue.

After a research i found the **dygraphs** library very interessing. So i tried it. The performance was so much better (at 4000 data points zooming was no problem) that i decided to stick with it. The only drawback is that this library has not many chart types out of the box.

However, here comes my dilemma. After a discussion with my superior he was surprised by my statement that Chart.js is that slow. He told me to make more researches relating this two libraries. He was convinced that Chart.js should be much better than dygraphs because of its popularity. But he never worked with neither of them so i should make the choice. Also he wants to use a library that will be reliable and maintained in the future. I had some problems with my researches because i didn't found a clear answer using google.

Now, can somebody explain me the two libraries regarding their perfomance and maintenance? Which one should i use (in your personal opinion)? Is Chart.js really that slow or can i get more power of it using alternative configuration? Is the popularity really matters for the decision?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am also interested in this question. Have you found anything interesting meanwhile?

Comment: I didn't try dygraphs yet, but I've seem people reporting migrating from ChartJS to dygraphs because of performance. https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/issues/75